# Adding a 2nd site to nginx

Tags: linux, nginx

I've had a single domain on my server which was setup by someone else however i'm trying to add a 2nd domain, after following a couple of tutorials off google i'm running into some issues.

Here is my default (i didn't create this one):

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    #server_name www.domain-one.net domain-one.net;
    root /var/www/html/domain-one;
    index index.php index.html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300000;
    }
}
```

That config works absolutly fine, According to the tutorial i was reading i had to setup another file so i did this and created a link but when i run `nginx -t` i get an error

`nginx: [emerg] a duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:2`

This is my 2nd config file which i created:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/domain-two;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name domain-two.info www.domain-two.info;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Guessing i'm doing something wrong?

Comment: You can't have two default servers on the same port.

Comment: So i should just remove the word `default_server` from the 2nd config ?

Comment: remove the conflicting/duplicate listen statements

Answer (score 3):

You want to have two server blocks. Both listening to the same IP address (I presume) but with different server names. Yes, remove the default_server since you can't have two.

```
server {
    listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80;
    server_name mysite.com;
    root /home/mysite;
...
}

server {
    listen       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80;
    server_name  mysite2.com;
    root /home/mysite2;
...
}
```

Comment: I did that and no longer get the error, However when i visit the domain-two.info it goes to the same page as the first domain?

Comment: @Exoon Make sure you have different roots set for each server.